# Flask-SimpleLDAP failing to install because of python-ldap prerequisite failure (Windows Active Directory)

Tags: python, windows, flask, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to install Flask-SimpleLDAP on a Windows machine so I can use Active Directory for authentication for a Dash app I have created.

I'm following this article - https://towardsdatascience.com/a-simple-way-to-integrate-dash-with-ldap-4d5d059ee3a6

The install is failing when it tries to build the wheel for "python-ldap", with the errors:

```
 Building wheel for python-ldap (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

C:\Users\canderson\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zixltin3\python-ldap\Modules\common.h(15): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'lber.h': No such file or directory   
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-ldap
```

I tried installing with both pip and pip3 with the same result, using the commands:

```
pip3 install flask-simpleldap

pip install flask-simpleldap
```

As a workaround I tried installing python3-ldap which installed no problem though it didn't help with the install of Flask-SimpleLDAP as the original (python-ldp) package is bundled into the install.

Do any of you know of a workaround for this or if there is another more freidnly version of Flask-SimpleLDAP available?

Comment: The PyPI package doesn't have a Windows binary so `pip` is trying to compile it from source. On Windows this is not always straightforward, especially when (as here) the packagers `#INCLUDE` a file but neglect to bundle that file in the package (which is often because every Linux distro can be expected to supply it, so they don't see the need). The easiest solution in such cases is to get an unofficial Windows binary from Christoph Gohlke's site: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap .

Comment: I see, thank you so much! Are you aware of any guidance on how to install one of these binaries. All of my python development to date has been on a Mac so still trying to get to grips with deploying python scripts on a Windows machine.

Comment: @BoarGules ... I figured out the process "py -m pip install './python_Levenshtein-0.12.2-pp37-pypy37_pp73-win_amd64.whl'" but the problem I am running into now is that it is returning the error "ERROR: python_Levenshtein-0.12.2-pp37-pypy37_pp73-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."

Comment: The `.whl` file is specific to a version of Python and an architecture. That file appears from the name to be for Python 3.7 64-bit. The message suggests a mismatch.

Comment: That's also very helpful! This has been incredibly informative all round, thank you @BoarGules